# How do I get an OAuth 2.0 authentication token in C#

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, restsharp

I have these settings:

- Auth URL (which happens to be a
  "https://login.microsoftonline.com/...") if that helps.
- Access Token URL "https://service.endpoint.com/api/oauth2/token"
- ClientId "abc"
- Clientsecret "123"

I then need to make a get call using a bearer token in the header.

I can get this to work in Postman, but have hit a wall trying to work out how to implement it in C#. I've been using RestSharp (but open to others). It all seems so opaque, when I thought it'd be pretty straight forward: it's a console app, so I don't need bells and whistles.

Ultimately, I want my app to (programatically) get a token, then use that for my subsequent calls. I'd appreciate anyone pointing me to documentation or examples, that explains what I'm after clearly. Everything I've come across is partial or for services operating on a different flow.

Thanks.

Comment: is your question get solution, if yes please share here.

Comment: Yes, The selected answer is below. There's also a number of good alternatives in the other answers.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

In Postman, click *Generate Code* and then in *Generate Code Snippets* dialog you can select a different coding language, including C# (RestSharp).

Also, you should only need the access token URL. The form parameters are then:

```
grant_type=client_credentials
client_id=abc    
client_secret=123
```

Code Snippet:

```
/* using RestSharp; // https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp/ */

var client = new RestClient("https://service.endpoint.com/api/oauth2/token");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=abc&client_secret=123", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

From the response body you can then obtain your access token. For instance for a *Bearer* token type you can then add the following header to subsequent authenticated requests:

```
request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer <access_token>");
```

Comment: Brilliant, worked perfectly - I'll blame noobness for not noticing that I could change Generate Code language. I also discovered (after posting this) that I needed to change the Security protocol `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;` is required too (at least in my case), other wise status codes '0' are encountered.

Comment: What namespace are you using, I am not familiar with RestClient

Comment: share code for access_token using the response. i am unable to find it. i want access_token and Refresh_token as well.

Comment: You should never allow this without authenticating the user first.

Comment: I've done it using nodejs in postman coding section

Comment: if you have `scope` then add scope into the response body

Answer (score 118):

The Rest Client answer is perfect! (I upvoted it)

But, just in case you want to go "raw"

..........

I got this to work with HttpClient.

"abstractly" what you are doing is

1. creating a POST request.
2. with a body of payload "type" of 'x-www-form-urlencoded'. ( see FormUrlEncodedContent https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.formurlencodedcontent?view=net-5.0 and note the constructor : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.formurlencodedcontent.-ctor?view=net-5.0)
3. and in the payload of 'type' : x-www-form-urlencoded, you are putting in certain values like the grant_type, client_id, client_secret etc.

Side note, try to get it working in PostMan, and then it is easier to "code it up" using the code below.

But here we go, code using HttpClient.

Side note, the newtonsoft references are to "bridge the gap" between c# naming standards and the json-element names. (partial code example immediately below). a C# property should be PascalCase, and the json element name (in this case) is "snake-case".

```
[JsonProperty("access_token")]
public string AccessToken { get; set; }
```

If you're at dotnet-core 5.0 and beyond. you can probably use System.Text.Json instead.

But here we go:

.......

```
/*
.nuget\packages\newtonsoft.json\12.0.1
.nuget\packages\system.net.http\4.3.4
*/
        
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
    
    
    private static async Task<Token> GetElibilityToken(HttpClient client)
    {
        string baseAddress = @"https://blah.blah.blah.com/oauth2/token";

        string grant_type = "client_credentials";
        string client_id = "myId";
        string client_secret = "shhhhhhhhhhhhhhItsSecret";

        var form = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"grant_type", grant_type},
                    {"client_id", client_id},
                    {"client_secret", client_secret},
                };

        HttpResponseMessage tokenResponse = await client.PostAsync(baseAddress, new FormUrlEncodedContent(form));
        var jsonContent = await tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Token tok = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(jsonContent);
        return tok;
    }
    
    
internal class Token
{
    [JsonProperty("access_token")]
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("token_type")]
    public string TokenType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("expires_in")]
    public int ExpiresIn { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("refresh_token")]
    public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
}
```

Here is another  working example (based off the answer above)......with a few more tweaks.  Sometimes the token-service is finicky:

```
    private static async Task<Token> GetATokenToTestMyRestApiUsingHttpClient(HttpClient client)
    {
        /* this code has lots of commented out stuff with different permutations of tweaking the request  */

        /* this is a version of asking for token using HttpClient.  aka, an alternate to using default libraries instead of RestClient */

        OAuthValues oav = GetOAuthValues(); /* object has has simple string properties for TokenUrl, GrantType, ClientId and ClientSecret */

        var form = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "grant_type", oav.GrantType },
                    { "client_id", oav.ClientId },
                    { "client_secret", oav.ClientSecret }
                };

        /* now tweak the http client */
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("cache-control", "no-cache");

        /* try 1 */
        ////client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        /* try 2 */
        ////client.DefaultRequestHeaders            .Accept            .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));//ACCEPT header

        /* try 3 */
        ////does not compile */client.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        ////application/x-www-form-urlencoded

        HttpRequestMessage req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, oav.TokenUrl);
        /////req.RequestUri = new Uri(baseAddress);
        
        req.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(form);

        ////string jsonPayload = "{\"grant_type\":\"" + oav.GrantType + "\",\"client_id\":\"" + oav.ClientId + "\",\"client_secret\":\"" + oav.ClientSecret + "\"}";
        ////req.Content = new StringContent(jsonPayload,                                                Encoding.UTF8,                                                "application/json");//CONTENT-TYPE header

        req.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        /* now make the request */
        ////HttpResponseMessage tokenResponse = await client.PostAsync(baseAddress, new FormUrlEncodedContent(form));
        HttpResponseMessage tokenResponse = await client.SendAsync(req);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("HttpResponseMessage.ReasonPhrase='{0}'", tokenResponse.ReasonPhrase));

        if (!tokenResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            throw new HttpRequestException("Call to get Token with HttpClient failed.");
        }

        var jsonContent = await tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Token tok = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(jsonContent);

        return tok;
    }
```

APPEND

Bonus Material!

If you ever get a

> "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation
> procedure."

exception......you can wire in a handler to see what is going on (and massage if necessary)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MyTokenRetrieverWithExtraStuff
    {
        public static async Task<Token> GetElibilityToken()
        {
            using (HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler())
            {
                httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = CertificateValidationCallBack;
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
                {
                    return await GetElibilityToken(client);
                }
            }
        }

        private static async Task<Token> GetElibilityToken(HttpClient client)
        {
            // throws certificate error if your cert is wired to localhost // 
            //string baseAddress = @"https://127.0.0.1/someapp/oauth2/token";

            //string baseAddress = @"https://localhost/someapp/oauth2/token";

        string baseAddress = @"https://blah.blah.blah.com/oauth2/token";

        string grant_type = "client_credentials";
        string client_id = "myId";
        string client_secret = "shhhhhhhhhhhhhhItsSecret";

        var form = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"grant_type", grant_type},
                    {"client_id", client_id},
                    {"client_secret", client_secret},
                };

            HttpResponseMessage tokenResponse = await client.PostAsync(baseAddress, new FormUrlEncodedContent(form));
            var jsonContent = await tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Token tok = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(jsonContent);
            return tok;
        }

        private static bool CertificateValidationCallBack(
        object sender,
        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate,
        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain,
        System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            // If the certificate is a valid, signed certificate, return true.
            if (sslPolicyErrors == System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.None)
            {
                return true;
            }

            // If there are errors in the certificate chain, look at each error to determine the cause.
            if ((sslPolicyErrors & System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors) != 0)
            {
                if (chain != null && chain.ChainStatus != null)
                {
                    foreach (System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainStatus status in chain.ChainStatus)
                    {
                        if ((certificate.Subject == certificate.Issuer) &&
                           (status.Status == System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainStatusFlags.UntrustedRoot))
                        {
                            // Self-signed certificates with an untrusted root are valid. 
                            continue;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (status.Status != System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainStatusFlags.NoError)
                            {
                                // If there are any other errors in the certificate chain, the certificate is invalid,
                                // so the method returns false.
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                // When processing reaches this line, the only errors in the certificate chain are 
                // untrusted root errors for self-signed certificates. These certificates are valid
                // for default Exchange server installations, so return true.
                return true;
            }


            /* overcome localhost and 127.0.0.1 issue */
            if ((sslPolicyErrors & System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch) != 0)
            {
                if (certificate.Subject.Contains("localhost"))
                {
                    HttpRequestMessage castSender = sender as HttpRequestMessage;
                    if (null != castSender)
                    {
                        if (castSender.RequestUri.Host.Contains("127.0.0.1"))
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return false;

        }


        public class Token
        {
            [JsonProperty("access_token")]
            public string AccessToken { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("token_type")]
            public string TokenType { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("expires_in")]
            public int ExpiresIn { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("refresh_token")]
            public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
        }

    }
}
```

........................

I recently found (Jan/2020) an article about all this.  I'll add a link here....sometimes having 2 different people show/explain it helps someone trying to learn it.

http://luisquintanilla.me/2017/12/25/client-credentials-authentication-csharp/

Comment: Thanks for this! Helps with trying to keep the NuGet packages to a minimum where possible.

Comment: how about a permutation where a certificate is used?

Comment: Could you provide a link to which oauth2 grant-type to which you are referring?          https://alexbilbie.com/guide-to-oauth-2-grants/            at the end of the day, you are just massaging the http-request that is oauth flavored (has certain headers, certain items in the payloads, etc, etc)

Comment: I use this one for a wrong client id, It is supposed to throw an exception but not. I used try catch blocks but the code didn't hit there not sure why?

Comment: What is the value of your : HttpResponseMessage.StatusCode Property  (in this code example in my answer, that is probably tokenResponse.StatusCode ) ?     https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.statuscode?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Any example to create/generate access token? i wanted to avoid indentityserver4

Comment: Reading a token... from a STS (security token service) and generating a Token (being a STS) are radically different things.

Comment: Thank you! The link at the end of the answer has changed. It is now https://www.luisquintanilla.me/posts/client-credentials-authentication-csharp.html

Answer (score 18):

Here is a complete example. Right click on the solution to manage nuget packages and get Newtonsoft and RestSharp:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using RestSharp;
using System;


namespace TestAPI
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string id = "xxx";
            string secret = "xxx";

            var client = new RestClient("https://xxx.xxx.com/services/api/oauth2/token");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
            request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=all&client_id=" + id + "&client_secret=" + secret, ParameterType.RequestBody);
            RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

            dynamic resp = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
            string token = resp.access_token;            

            client = new RestClient("https://xxx.xxx.com/services/api/x/users/v1/employees");
            request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
            response = client.Execute(request);
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: using above code getting  an error:
An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Path '', line 0, position 0.

Comment: @RaviKantSingh you  have to check your `response`. I guess your request was failed, therefore you got the wrong reponse, which JObject cant understand

Answer (score 12):

I used ADAL.NET/ [Microsoft Identity Platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/) to achieve this. The advantage of using it was that we get a nice wrapper around the code to acquire `AccessToken` and we get additional features like `Token Cache` out-of-the-box. From the [documentation](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/ADAL.NET-supports-multiple-application-architectures-and-multiple-platforms#why-use-adalnet-):

> Why use ADAL.NET ?
>
> ADAL.NET V3 (Active Directory Authentication Library for .NET) enables developers of .NET applications to acquire tokens in order to call secured Web APIs. These Web APIs can be the Microsoft Graph, or 3rd party Web APIs.

Here is the code snippet:

```
    // Import Nuget package: Microsoft.Identity.Client
    public class AuthenticationService
    {
         private readonly List<string> _scopes;
         private readonly IConfidentialClientApplication _app;

        public AuthenticationService(AuthenticationConfiguration authentication)
        {

             _app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                         .Create(authentication.ClientId)
                         .WithClientSecret(authentication.ClientSecret)
                         .WithAuthority(authentication.Authority)
                         .Build();

           _scopes = new List<string> {$"{authentication.Audience}/.default"};
       }

       public async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
       {
           var authenticationResult = await _app.AcquireTokenForClient(_scopes) 
                                                .ExecuteAsync();
           return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
       }
   }
```

Comment: Could the downvoter provide the reason for downvote?

Comment: Isn't it limited to Microsoft tokens?

Comment: The documentation says it should work with 3rd party as well.

Comment: I don’t read that. From what I understand, the only token provider is Azure AD.

Comment: where is authenticationconfiguration coming from?

Comment: ADAL is deprecated now, @AnkitVijay can you share a link to the documentation that says it should work with 3rd party?

Comment: @Konrad ADAL is superseded by MSAL. Please read the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-overview

Answer (score 4):

You may use the following code to get the bearer token.

```
private string GetBearerToken()
{
    var client = new RestClient("https://service.endpoint.com");
    client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("abc", "123");
    var request = new RestRequest("api/oauth2/token", Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    request.AddParameter("application/json", "{ \"grant_type\":\"client_credentials\" }", 
    ParameterType.RequestBody);
    var responseJson = _client.Execute(request).Content;
    var token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(responseJson)["access_token"].ToString();
    if(token.Length == 0)
    {
        throw new AuthenticationException("API authentication failed.");
    }
    return token;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This example get token thouth **HttpWebRequest**

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(pathapi);
        request.Method = "POST";
        string postData = "grant_type=password";
        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] byte1 = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        request.ContentLength = byte1.Length;
        Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        newStream.Write(byte1, 0, byte1.Length);

        HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;            
        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            getreaderjson = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried this way to get OAuth 2.0 authentication token using c#

```
namespace ConsoleApp2
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(GetToken());
            Console.Read();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get access token from api
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static string GetToken()
        {
            string wClientId = "#######";
            string wClientSecretKey = "*********************";
            string wAccessToken;

//--------------------------- Approch-1 to get token using HttpClient -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage;
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                HttpRequestMessage tokenRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://localhost:1001/oauth/token");
                HttpContent httpContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(
                        new[]
                        {
                                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials"),
                        });
                tokenRequest.Content = httpContent;
                tokenRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(wClientId + ":" + wClientSecretKey)));
                responseMessage =  client.SendAsync(tokenRequest).Result;
            }
            string ResponseJSON=   responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;


//--------------------------- Approch-2 to get token using HttpWebRequest and deserialize json object into ResponseModel class -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


            byte[] byte1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("grant_type=client_credentials");

            HttpWebRequest oRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://localhost:1001/oauth/token") as HttpWebRequest;
            oRequest.Accept = "application/json";
            oRequest.Method = "POST";
            oRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            oRequest.ContentLength = byte1.Length;
            oRequest.KeepAlive = false;
            oRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(wClientId + ":" + wClientSecretKey)));
            Stream newStream = oRequest.GetRequestStream();
            newStream.Write(byte1, 0, byte1.Length);

            WebResponse oResponse = oRequest.GetResponse();

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(oResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                var oJsonReponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
                ResponseModel oModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseModel>(oJsonReponse);
                wAccessToken = oModel.access_token;
            }

            return wAccessToken;
        }
    }
  
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //---------------------------------- Response Class---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /// <summary>
    /// De-serialize Web response Object into model class to read  
    /// </summary>
    public class ResponseModel
    {
        public string scope { get; set; }
        public string token_type { get; set; }
        public string expires_in { get; set; }
        public string refresh_token { get; set; }
        public string access_token { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  It's simple and humble. !!!

Answer (score 2):

My client is using `grant_type=Authorization_code` workflow.

I have below settings:

Auth URL (which happens to be a "https://login.microsoftonline.com/...") if that helps.

Access Token URL: "https://service.endpoint.com/api/oauth2/token"
ClientId: "xyz"
Clientsecret: "123dfsdf"

I then need to make a get call using a bearer token in the header. I tried all the above code sample, But whatever I will land on Microsoft - Sign in to you account" page as

```
"\r\n\r\n<!-- Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. -->\r\n<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html dir=\"ltr\" class=\"\" lang=\"en\">\r\n<head>\r\n    <title>Sign in to your account</title>\r\n "
```

I am able to execute on Postman and I observed there are 2 calls in console.

1. GET call for Authorization Code
2. POST call with above Authorization Code appended in the call to the the Access token.

I tried to execute the above GET call in a separately in POSTMAN, when I do that I will be prompted with microsoftonline login page, when I enter my credentials I will get salesforce error.

if anyone can provide sample code or examples of `Authorization_code` `grand_type` workflow That will be very great help...

Answer (score 1):

**Clearly:**

Server side generating a token example

```
private string GenerateToken(string userName)
{
    var someClaims = new Claim[]{
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.UniqueName, userName),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, GetEmail(userName)),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.NameId,Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
    };

    SecurityKey securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_settings.Tokenizer.Key));
    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
        issuer: _settings.Tokenizer.Issuer,
        audience: _settings.Tokenizer.Audience,
        claims: someClaims,
        expires: DateTime.Now.AddHours(_settings.Tokenizer.ExpiryHours),
        signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
    );

    return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
}
```

*(note: Tokenizer is my helper class that contains Issuer Audience etc..)*

**Definitely:**

Client side getting a token for **authentication**

```
    public async Task<string> GetToken()
    {
        string token = "";
        var siteSettings = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<SiteSettings>();

        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(siteSettings.PopularSearchRequest.StaticApiUrl);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        StatisticUserModel user = new StatisticUserModel()
        {
            Password = siteSettings.PopularSearchRequest.Password,
            Username = siteSettings.PopularSearchRequest.Username
        };

        string jsonUser = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user, Formatting.Indented);
        var stringContent = new StringContent(jsonUser, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = await client.PostAsync(siteSettings.PopularSearchRequest.StaticApiUrl + "/api/token/new", stringContent);
        token = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return token;
    }
```

You can use this token for the **authorization** (that is in the subsequent requests)

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel adds extensions to `HttpClient` to acquire tokens using different flows and the documentation is great too. It's very handy because you don't have to think how to implement it yourself. I'm not aware if any official MS implementation exists.