# Does MSAL work only with azure and Microsoft identity platform?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, identitymodel

I'm looking for some client library that can handle OAuth requests and automatically utilize refresh tokens when access token expires to acquire new token. I found https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/ that adds extensions to HttpClient but that's it. It leaves token management to you and you need to write a logic to refresh expired tokens and correctly handle timeouts etc.

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57779925/2828480) that recommends using ADAL (now deprecated) and it apparently works with 3rd party apis.

**TLDR:** Does  MSAL work only with Azure and Microsoft identity platform or it can be used with all kinds of APIs that use OAuth?

It looks like it always makes requests to `https://login.microsoftonline.com` and it doesn't seem to be possible to change endpoints for token etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSAL only works with Microsoft Identity Providers Such as [Azure AD, B2C and ADFS](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/1538#issuecomment-562638370).