# How to use HttpClient instead of RestClient in a .NET 6

Tags: c#, http, .net-6.0

For example my rest client looks something like this:

```
 var client = new RestClient("test/oauth/token");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\"client_id\":\test123123123\",\"client_secret\":\"fsdfsdhkfsjdhf\",\"audience\":\"https://test.auth0.com/api/v2/\",\"grant_type\":\"client_credentials\"}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

The code above works but I wanted to convert this to HTTP client instead, just not sure how to do it

Comment: RestClient uses HttpClient underneath. You shouldn't be writing JSON by hand either. This code can be replaced with `HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("test/oauth/token",someObject);` where `someObject` an object with the properties you want. BUT there are OAuth clients that can be used instead of hand-coded calls

Comment: Yes, but what if I don't want to use RestClient since it is a third party library ?

Comment: @HJ1990 then don't use it. There are a lot of examples how to use `HttpClient` (either directly or via `IHttpClientFactory`, the latter one preferable) to make requests. What is an exact problem?

Comment: I already posted the single line needed to POST an object as JSON

Comment: Loosely related.. but you can see 2 answers (one as RestClient, one as HttpClient) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38494279/how-do-i-get-an-oauth-2-0-authentication-token-in-c-sharp/53787718#53787718

Comment: I super agree with the "PostAsJsonAsync" comment.  Stop creating json (or xml) with string manipulation.  #please #beggingYou

Comment: Seeing the content of your JSON, I think you might be interested in OAuth/OIDC library such as IdentityModel to help you implement it correctly. See https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client/overview.html

Answer (score 2):

The are a lot of examples including [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/http/httpclient#http-post-as-json) on how to make requests with `HttpClient`. For example:

```cs
static async Task PostAsJsonAsync(HttpClient httpClient)
{
    using HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(
        "todos", 
        new Todo(UserId: 9, Id: 99, Title: "Show extensions", Completed: false));

    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
        .WriteRequestToConsole();

    var todo = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<Todo>();
    WriteLine($"{todo}\n");

    // Expected output:
    //   POST https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos HTTP/1.1
    //   Todo { UserId = 9, Id = 201, Title = Show extensions, Completed = False }
}
```

Currently the recommended pattern of setting up/creating/consuming `HttpClient`'s is by using `IHttpClientFactory`:

- [Use `IHttpClientFactory` to implement resilient HTTP requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests)
- [`IHttpClientFactory` with .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/httpclient-factory)
- [Make HTTP requests using `IHttpClientFactory` in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: Upvote.  And super-agree with the "learn how to use IHttpClientFactory"   (vs "new'ing up a new HttpClient)