# How to call rest api with an oauth 2.0 authentication token in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0

In POSTMAN Go to Authorization tab

- Select OAuth 2.0 from the Type dropdown
- Select Request Headers from Add authorization data to dropdown
- Fill the following information in Configure New Token section:
- Token Name: ‘My OAuth2 token’ (You can name it as your wish)
- Grant Type: Client Credentials
- Access Token URL: https://service.endpoint.com/api/oauth2/token
- Client ID: The Client_Id generated earlier (ABCD)
- Client Secret: The Client_Secret generated earlier(1234f)
- Click on Get New Access Token button

I then need to make a get call using a bearer token.

I can get this to work in Postman, but have hit a wall trying to work out how to implement it in C#.

I need C# code for calling a REST API with an access token.

Comment: [Does the link useful to you ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38579470/7687666)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a sample C# request to make and  Oauth call with authorization token.
Install the restSharp nuget package.

```
//#Install RestSharp nuget package
//using RestSharp
public async Task<RestResponse> getData(string authtoken)
{
    var options = new RestClientOptions("http://sampleUrl")
    {
        MaxTimeout = -1,
    };
    var client = new RestClient(options);
    var request = new RestRequest("/samplemethods/123", Method.Get);
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + authtoken);
    RestResponse response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
    Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
    return response;
}
```

Comment: How to pass Client Id &  Client_Secret